# Combine two RxJS Observables/Subscriptions and iterate through their data

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, angular-httpclient

I work with [Angular](https://angular.io/) (Version 7) and [RxJS](https://www.learnrxjs.io/) and make two api calls, each returning an observable, which I then subscribe to.

Now I have to combine these subscriptions, because the data from both observables are interdependent and I need them to implement certain functions (For example, a filter that checks if the id received from subcription2 appears in subscription1 and only then returns something..).

Since my code is very long, I have prepared a smaller sample version of it and marked the important places for me with comments:

```
getSomething(){
    /**
     * anIdFromSubscriptionTwo: An id that I need from subscription2
     */
    const subscription1 = this.service.getSomeStuff().subscription((someStuff) => {
        this.someStuff = stuff;
        this.someStuff.forEach((stuff) => {
            if(stuff.someProperty !== null && stuff.id === anIdFromSubscriptionTwo){
                ...
            }
        });
    } 

    /**
     * aIdFromSubscriptionOne: An id of type string that I get in the forEach loop inside of subscription1
     * aTypeFromSubscriptionOne: A type of type string that I get in the forEach loop inside of subscription1
     */
    const subscription2 = this.service.getSomeOtherStuff(aIdFromSubscriptionOne: string, aTypeFromSubscriptionOne: string).subscription((someOtherStuff) => {
        this.someOtherStuff = someOtherStuff;
        this.someOtherStuff.forEach(() => {
            // This is the only if statement I need, after combining the two subscriptions
            if(subscription1.stuff.someProperty !== null && subscription1.stuff.id === someOtherStuff.id){
                const properties: Image = {
                    id: // an id I need from subscription1
                    class: // a class I need from  subscription1
                    type: // a type I need from subscription2
                    ref: // a reference to the image url from subscription2
                    ...
                }
            }
        })  
    });
}
```

How can I combine these two subscriptions so that I can access their data in my forEach loop and compare or work with it generally?

Answer (score 0):

you use **switchMap** to avoid subscription inside another

```
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';


  this.service.getSomeStuff().pip(switchMap((someStuff) => {
        this.someStuff = someStuff;

      this.service.getSomeOtherStuff(aIdFromSubscriptionOne: string, aTypeFromSubscriptionOne: string)
       ).subscribe((someOtherStuff) => {
        this.someOtherStuff = someOtherStuff;
        this.someOtherStuff.forEach(() => {
        // make a foreach loop here on someStuff to check if someOtherStuff exist in some Stuff
          this.someStuff.foreach((somestuff) => {
             if(somestuff.someProperty !== null && somestuff.id === someOtherStuff.id){
               const properties: Image = {
                id: // an id I need from subscription1
                class: // a class I need from  subscription1
                type: // a type I need from subscription2
                ref: // a reference to the image url from subscription2
                ...
               }
             }
           });  
         }); 
      });   
  });
```

Comment: But can I also check whether an ID from the first subscription (outer subscription) also occurs in the second subscription (inner subscription)? Because that is one of the conditions of my if statement and only then should something be done with this specific entries.

Comment: in that case you can use switchMap, i've updated my answer

Comment: But this way I can't use the aIdFromSubscriptionOne and aTypeFromSubscriptionOne parameters. Hmm..

Comment: inside switchMap, you have someStuff after that you can subscribe to get someOtherStuff so you have both

Comment: But I need a forEach loop for that, since this.someStuff = someStuff is an array from which I have to read out the respective ID? Right?